# window.location.href/reload causing AngularJS [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached

Tags: javascript, angularjs, window.location

I know this is causing the problem, as if I were to change `window.location.href/reload` to `$location.path()`, it works just fine. <strike>Now, I do not see any performance errors when running the code (usability)</strike> Just kidding, this breaks the app in IE but works in Chrome when using `window`.

What I am doing is forcing some updates to reflect on the site when a user logs in/out, and to do that I need to refresh the page once I change their route. Using `$location.path` and `$state.go` change my URL but do not reload/refresh the page to reflect the site updates.

Is there any way for AngularJS to natively redirect and reload a route/page without getting this loop warning/error? Or is there a way to still use the `window.location.href/reload` and now have AngularJS freak out?

The error

> Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
>
> Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [["fn: function
>   $locationWatch() {\n      var oldUrl = $browser.url();\n      var
>   currentReplace = $location.$$replace;\n\n      if (!changeCounter ||
>   oldUrl != $location.absUrl()) {\n        changeCounter++;\n
>   $rootScope.$evalAsync(function() {\n          if
>   ($rootScope.$broadcast('$locationChangeStart', $location.absUrl(),
>   oldUrl).\n              defaultPrevented) {\n
>   $location.$$parse(oldUrl);\n          } else {\n
>   $browser.url($location.absUrl(), currentReplace);\n
>   afterLocationChange(oldUrl);\n          }\n        });\n      }\n
>   $location.$$replace = false;\n\n      return changeCounter;\n    };
>   newVal: 8; oldVal: 7","fn: function(context) {\n          try {\n
>   for(var i = 0, ii = length, part; i

And then there is a paragraph-long error below those starting with:

> [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
>   Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations....

Answer (score 2):

You may try replacing the href inside a setTimeout. That helped in my case.

```
$setTimeout(function() { $window.location.href = newUrl; }, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$state` actually has a `reload()` function to do exactly this:

`$state.reload();`

You can read about it in the ui-router $state [docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state#methods_reload).

If you need to redirect as well, you can force a reload on state transition by passing the `reload: true` option to `$state.go()`:

`$state.go('stateName', {}, {reload: true});`

Comment: Do I need to add ui-router then, just for this one feature?

Comment: Your questions mentions use of `$state.go()`, I had assumed you were already using it. If not, Angular also provides the `$route` service that provides a similar functionality. Inject it into your controller, and call `$route.reload()` where you need to.

Comment: I have tried putting `$route.reload` in controllers, but it never fires. :/